# Use Test listeners with callTestCase() function

Tags: selenium, katalon-studio

Is it possible to use Test Listeners (*@BeforeTestCase* and *@AfterTestCase*) before and after *WebUI.callTestCase(…)* ?

Or at least, get *TestCaseContext* after execution of *WebUI.callTestCase(...)* ?

To do something like :

```
TestCaseContext tcc = WebUI.callTestCase(…)
System.out.println(tcc.getStatus())
...
```

Because currently, I don't have any information about the execution...

Thanks a lot,

Regards

Answer (score 1):

No, `TestCaseContext`, together with `@BeforeTestCase` and `@AfterTestCase` refer to the current test case (i.e. *caller* TC, not *callee* TC).

What you could do is to create a global variable `CalleeStatus` and write the status of the callee TC to it in its `@AfterTestCase`

Callee TC:

```
@AfterTestCase
def afterTestcase(TestCaseContext testCaseContext) {
    GlobalVariable.calleeStatus = testCaseContext..getTestCaseStatus()
    WebUI.closeBrowser()
}
```

Caller TC:

```
WebUI.callTestCase(…)
println(GlobalVariable.calleeStatus)
```